# uTorrent on Startup

Tags: firefox, startup, chromium, utorrent

I have installed uTorrent as explained [here on sysads.co.uk](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-utorrent-3-3-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/)

Every thing went smoothly.

After that I have added to startup applications the command

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
```

Now when I startup the PC I just need to go to `localhost:8080/gui` and provide user name: `admin`

I have installed both Firefox and Chromium, but I always use Firefox for my internet.

I want to add a command to startup that will launch minimized Chromium with uTorrent and automatic add username `admin` and timeout around 10 seconds.

I know to do `chromium-browser localhost:8080/gui/` but how to add username `admin`, timeout 10s and minimazed(-m)?

Answer (score 1):

Found part of the solution. I have installed epiphany-browser.
In startup applications, I have added

```
epiphany-browser  http ://localhost:8080/gui
```

Epiphany remembers username and password. I just tap <kbd>Enter</kbd> and I have `utserver` with gui.